# how to train a classifier using video datasets

Tags: machine-learning, classification

If I have a video dataset of a specific action , how could I use them to train a classifier that could be used later to classify this action.

Comment: You have to extract numerical information from the video.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is very generic. In general, there is no foul proof way of training a classifier that will work for everything. It highly depends on the data you are working with.

Here is the 'generic' pipeline:

- extract features from the video
- label your features (positive for the action you are looking for; negative otherwise)
- split your data into 2 (or 3) sets. One for training, one for testing and the other optionally for validation
- train a classifier on the labeled examples (e.g. SVM, Neural Network, Nearest Neighbor ...)
- validate the results on the validation data, if that is appropriate for the algorithm
- test on data you haven't used for training.

You can start with some machine learning tools here http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

Make sure you **never** touch the **test** data for any other purposes than **testing**

Good luck

Comment: if you have a reference ( tutorial or lecture to do every step will be great)

Comment: Do you have reference to this particular use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Almost 10 years later, here's an updated answer.

1. Set up a camera and collect raw video data
2. Save it somewhere in form of single frames. Do this yourself locally or using a cloud bucket or use a service like [Sieve API](https://sievedata.com/). Helpful repo [linked here](https://github.com/Sieve-Data/automatic-video-processing).
3. Export from Sieve or cloud bucket to get data labeled. Do this yourself or using some service like [Scale Rapid](https://scale.com/rapid).
4. Split your dataset into train, test, and validation.
5. Train a classifier on the labeled samples. Use transfer learning over some existing model and fine-tune just the last few layers.
6. Run your model over the test set after each training epoch and save the one with the best test set performance.
7. Evaluate your model at the end using the validation set.

There are many repos that can help you get started: https://github.com/weiaicunzai/awesome-image-classification

The two things that can help you ensure best results include 1. **high quality labeled data** and 2. **a diverse, curated dataset**. That's what [Sieve](https://sievedata.com/) can help with!